# Which Goes Where? Hint: Old Kid?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Usual folks! Each ellipse corresponds to an as-yet-unknown category - two tiles are placed for you - and each remaining tile belongs to at least one category - so the question remains - which goes where and why?

[image]

Comment: Would adding the movies tag be a spoiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolved Venn diagram:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

Because the two ellipses represent:

> The surnames of winners of the Academy Awards for **Best Actor** and **Best Actress** when the words are suffixed with **MAN** (clued by 'old kid', as well as these words doubling as entries in the diagram):
>
>  Best Actor winners:
>  [Ronald **COL**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Colman) (*A Double Life*, 1946)
>  [Gene **HACK**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Hackman) (*The French Connection*, 1971)
>  [Paul **NEW**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Newman) (*The Color of Money*, 1986)
>  [Gary **OLD**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Oldman) (*Darkest Hour*, 2017)
>
>  Best Actress winners:
>  [Ingrid **BERG**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingrid_Bergman) (*Gaslight*, 1944 & *Anastasia*, 1956)
>  [Olivia **COL**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivia_Colman) (*The Favourite*, 2017)
>  [Nicole **KID**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicole_Kidman) (*The Hours*, 2002)
>  [Natalie **PORT**man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalie_Portman) (*Black Swan*, 2010)
>
>  Thus the word 'COL' appears in the intersection of the two ellipses.
>
>  *NB The year quoted in each case is the year of the Academy Awards ceremony, not necessarily the year the movie was released.*